# How to get All users All mail on Exchange server using EWS API?

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

using EWS api I get all mail inbox of particular user is it possible. but how to get all users of all mails of my company exchange server. this possible using power shell but how it will do using programmatically. thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried? How many exchange users does your company have? Do you have delegate access to all the mailboxes?

Comment: yes I hve delegate access to all other user and there are 60 users I have done for finding mailbox of other user at a time not for all

Answer (score -1):

If you want to enumerate all Email then you need to do this a mailbox folder at a time. EWS (and all the Mailbox access API's) are user API's so your application runs in that context, if you need to scale it they run multiple threads and use EWS Impersonation etc so you can access multiple mailboxes simultaneously.

If your question was how you search across multiple mailboxes which is what you can do in Powershell then look at using eDiscovery https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190897(v=exchg.150).aspx